# ODS tagsets.msoddice2k_x ".xls". Exporting number as string

Tags: sas, sas-ods

My problem Is related with exporting a table from sas using ODS. Well, when exporting my table the data its a number declared as a string (Example 0001, 0003). When exporting this table, in my exell appears 1 instead of 0001, the number needs to have the previous ceros before, it's a necesary condition.

What I canot understand is why it is not tranported literaly when its a string and not a number.

Thank you all¡

```
proc report data=test.Information nowd noheader;
  col1;
  format col1 $10.;
run;
```

Comment: check out FORMATTING DATA section in the following link : http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/msoffice2k/index.html

Comment: @sushil That looks like an answer to me (with supporting information of course)

Comment: Sorry for the late response¡. Thank you again @sushil exactly what I was serching¡